# Passing symbol to block methods

Tags: ruby, syntax, block, symbols

Some block methods such as `inject` can optionally take a symbol instead of a block:

```
%w[a b c].inject(&:+)
# => "abc"
%w[a b c].inject(:+)
# => "abc"
%w[a b c].inject("", :+)
# => "abc"
```

while other block methods such as `map` cannot:

```
%w[a b c].map(&:upcase)
# => ["A", "B", "C"]
%w[a b c].map(:upcase)
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Why can't the latter take a symbol?

Answer (score 1):

For `inject`, a block (or a substitute) is obligatory. If it weren't passed a block, then there has to be at least one argument, the last argument has to be a symbol, and the block would be constructed out of it. Whatever the arity, there is no ambiguity; the last argument is used to construct a block when the block is lacking.

For `map`, a block is optional. When there is no block given, then the return value would be an `Enumerator` instance. Hence, from the information whether a block was passed or not, it cannot be decided whether the last argument should be used to construct a block.

In the particular case of `map`, it does not take an argument, so there is a sense in saying that an extra argument should be taken as a block, but it makes things complicated to judge whether that last argument is to be taken as a block depending on the arity. And it also loses the future possibility of changing the arity of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i know this operator `&` to_proc, `inject()` method accept 2 args first accum second `proc`, but `map()` accept only one args `proc` or `block`. In `inject()` first args(accum) can be first item in enum.

Comment: Look at my second example. The first argument is not the first item in enum.

Comment: you about `inject` example or `map`? `Inject` take args without you notation. @SergioTulentsev right. this special case about `inject` and `map` i think.

Comment: this same thing `%w[a b c].inject(:+)` and `%w[a b c].inject("", :+)` try pass wrong accum like `%w[a b c].inject(0, :+)` this raise `TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum`

Answer (score 0):

It's just a special handling for this special case in some methods and lack of such handling in the others.

Comment: You mean it was arbitrary?

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure of it.